# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in Z:\ on line 94 (-данная строка if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$result= mysqli_query($link,'SELECT login FROM table_products');


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

do
{
if ($row["images"]!="" && file_exists("./uploads_images/".$row["images"]))
{
    $img_path = './uploads_images/'.$row["images"];
    $max_width= 200;
    $max_height= 200;
    list($width, $height)= getimagesize($img_path);
    $ratioh = $max_height/$height;
    $ratiow = $max_width/$width;
    $ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow);
    $width=  intval($ratio*$width);
    $height = intval($ratio*$height);

} else{
    $img_path ="/images/no-images.png";
    $width=110;
    $height=200;
}
echo '

 <li>
 <div class="block-images-grid">
 <img src="'.$img_path.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$heigh.'"/>
 </div>
 <p class="style-title-grid"><a href="">'.$row["title"].'</a></p>
 <ul class="reviews-and-counts-gird">
 <li><img src="/images/comment-icon.png" /><p>0</p></li>
 <li><img src="/images/eye-icon.png" /><p>0</p></li>
 </ul>
 <a class="add-cart-style-grid"></a>
 <p class="style-price-grid"><strong>'.$row["price"].' </strong>p.</p>
<div class="mini-features">
'.$row["mini_feartures"].'
</div>
 </li>


 ';

} 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
}

?>
```

Comment: Проблема в 1ой строчке. $result === false => Либо ошибка запроса, либо ошибка соединения

Comment: вы посмотрите на список похожих вопросов справа, они там все одинаковые  с вашим